# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]

Tags: sql-server, oledbexception

In one of Win2k8R2 x64 machine, I have a C# console program which connects to a remote sql server 2008 R2 instance. Quite often I am seeing below exception message

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be  problem with the credentials you are supplying.

This may help you in troubleshooting the exception

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y8t7kbw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try do as follow:

```
1)    Launch regedit.exe
2)    Add DWORD value named SynAttackProtect under registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\
3)    Set data value to 0
```

Full explan read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/04/12/574608.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/05/27/sql-server-intermittent-connectivity-issue.aspx)

Comment: Both links are dead now.